# Create XSD file from GPX file

Tags: java, xml, xsd, unmarshalling, gpx

I have a GPX file and I want to unmarshall it to java classed.
To achieve that first I need to create an XSD file, which will help me to unmarshall.
I dont know how to create XSD from GPX file, please help.
Following is the sample GPX file content that I am trying to generate XSD for.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="AMG Track Pace" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:amg="https://www.mercedes-amg.com/xsd/gpx-ext">
    <metadata>
        <name>Sandown International Raceway</name>
        <time>2019-10-21T22:51:10</time>
        <extensions>
            <trackMeta>
                <amg:name>Sandown International Raceway</amg:name>
                <amg:guid>00000000-27bc-b800-f7c2-000000a1ae9b</amg:guid>
                <amg:rec>1</amg:rec>
                <amg:length>3131.9</amg:length>
                <amg:bestRaceNumber>0</amg:bestRaceNumber>
                <amg:bestLapNumber>0</amg:bestLapNumber>
            </trackMeta>
        </extensions>
    </metadata>
    <trk>
        <trkseg>
            <trkpt lat="-37.9493280" lon="145.1643630">
                <ele>53.9</ele>
                <extensions>
                    <heading>176.001</heading>
                    <distanceFromStart>0</distanceFromStart>
                </extensions>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="-37.9493284" lon="145.1643630">
                <ele>53.9</ele>
                <extensions>
                    <heading>175.972</heading>
                    <distanceFromStart>0.0452761</distanceFromStart>
                </extensions>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="-37.9493286" lon="145.1643630">
                <ele>53.9</ele>
                <extensions>
                    <heading>175.961</heading>
                    <distanceFromStart>0.0689919</distanceFromStart>
                </extensions>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="-37.9493287" lon="145.1643630">
                <ele>53.9</ele>
                <extensions>
                    <heading>175.949</heading>
                    <distanceFromStart>0.0797715</distanceFromStart>
                </extensions>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="-37.9493288" lon="145.1643630">
                <ele>53.9</ele>
                <extensions>
                    <heading>175.926</heading>
                    <distanceFromStart>0.0883952</distanceFromStart>
                </extensions>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="-37.9493288" lon="145.1643630">
                <ele>53.9</ele>
                <extensions>
                    <heading>175.886</heading>
                    <distanceFromStart>0.0905511</distanceFromStart>
                </extensions>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="-37.9493289" lon="145.1643630">
                <ele>53.9</ele>
                <extensions>
                    <heading>175.864</heading>
                    <distanceFromStart>0.0970189</distanceFromStart>
                </extensions>
            </trkpt>
        </trkseg>
    </trk>
</gpx>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create a [GPX](https://www.topografix.com/gpx.asp) XSD because there's already an [official GPX 1.1 XSD](https://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd).